# YQL error into pressure when use u=c

Tags: yql, weather, measure

good morning,
I starting to use a YQL for extract a weather condition for my town.

I live in Italy and set the query with u=c parameter, but in this case the pressure value is wrong.

If I request without u=c the query return:
   atmosphere
     pressure   "1006.0"

but if I send a query with u=c return is:
   atmosphere
     pressure   "34067.08"

my query is:
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="codogno,it") and u=c&format=json

Answer (score 0):

I think Yahoo got it wrong. So if you requested u=c then it returns millibars but it is not expected value you must convert it to inch then you got the real millibars.

then if you requested u=f then it returns in but it is not as expected value it is a millibars so you must again convert it to an in.

Maybe we should consider a new provider.